# Parameter not passed from program to stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I am passing the parameter like in C# page,

```
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);  
cmd.CommandText = commandtype.storedprocedure;   
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?user", user)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", name);
```

On the mysql stored procedures used 2 parameter for record exists finds

```
@id integer,
@name varchar(200)

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE  id = @id and mode =0 limit 1 )
    THEN
        UPDATE usertable  SET name = name where id=@id and mode = 0;
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO usertable  (name,  mode)VALUES (@name`enter code here`,0);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: `cmd.CommantText = commandtype.storedprocedure` doesn't make too much sense. It should be `cmd.CommandType = commandtype.storedprocedure`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of sending variables to a stored proc that I've used with no problem:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbTpye.Varchar).Value = name;
```

I think you can specify variable by size and type like this:

```
SqlDbTpye.Varchar,200
```

But not able to test that right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the prefixes for the parameters match. If you use "@" in your stored procedure, you need to use "@" in C#, too, not "?".

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
```

Comment: Hi I found, need to use ? symbol instead of @, its working, thanks for your support, i corrected the procedure as,